# How can I change column type on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5

I insert a column in my sqlite with a wrong type "stringimage".

[image]

How can I change the column type to string?

I tried `change_column :users, :uid, :string`

and

```
def up
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.change :uid, :stringimage
  end
end
def down
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.change :uid, :string
  end
end
```

but it doesn't works.
I tried many things but none of it works, maybe because I'm using rails 5.

Comment: After changing, did you run migration for the same ?

Comment: Have you consider running `rake db:migrate`

Comment: yes I runned `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Need to write following two definitions into your migration :

```
def up
  change_column :my_table, :my_column, :string
end

def down
  change_column :my_table, :my_column, :stringimage
end
```

Comment: I got this error: `== 20160722050406 ChangeUid: migrating 
-- change_column(:users, :uid, :string)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
C:/Sites/AirProject/db/migrate/20160722050406_change_uid.rb:3:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
C:/Sites/AirProject/db/migrate/20160722050406_change_uid.rb:3:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'`
`

Comment: First you need to run `rake db:rollback` command, and then perform `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I got this: `== 20160722050406 ChangeUid: migrating ========
== 20160722050406 ChangeUid: migrated (0.0000s)` ... but nothing was changed on my column

Comment: Can you please provide your last migration file content ?

Comment: You also can have this code, exactly after your class declaration :
`def change
    change_column :users, :uid, :string
  end`

Comment: This is the content of my last migration file `class ChangeUid < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change 
 change_column :users, :uid, :string    
  end
end
` ... Now i runned `rake db:migrate`, I didn´t get error, but the column type wasn't changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118007/discussion-between-hardik-kanjariya--and-s-a).

Answer (score 1):

Note that change_column is an irreversible migration. It will cause an error if you try to rollback. To prevent this, modify the usual change method in the migration to use two separate up and down methods like this:

```
class ChangeUsersUidType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :users, :uid, :string
  end

  def down
    change_column :users, :uid, :stringimage
  end
end
```

If you liked this answer you can read more in this article: https://kolosek.com/rails-change-database-column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options):` Changes the column to a different type using the same parameters as add_column.

Comment: I got this: `rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
C:/Sites/AirProject/db/migrate/20160722050406_change_uid.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
C:/Sites/AirProject/db/migrate/20160722050406_change_uid.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`